# SDL 2.0.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 - Multiple displays fullscreen problem

Tags: c++, linux, fullscreen, sdl-2

- I have a **vertical dual screen setup** with each monitor's size of 1920x1080. 
  My software must run on both screens with a single **SDL window (1920x2160) on fullscreeen**.
- The SDL_WindowFlags mask used in the window creation is the following : (SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP).

  *Since SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP polls the actual hardware resolution (as far as i know) I am presented with a **single screen** of 1920x1080 (the first half of the software's GUI) rather than 1920x2160 so the second screen is not drawn.*

---

A workaround is to change the mask to (SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS) to run it in windowed borderless mode but that case is not applicable to the software needs (its required and it should not be done like this).

Any recommendations for running the software in real fullscreen, excluding splitting the logic into many SDL windows, are welcomed.

Comment: "excluding splitting" - you actually need to create a swap chain (possibly on different adapters) per output

Comment: How are your screens organized? Does any other Program expands to both screens if you make it fullscreen?

Comment: Screen 0 (main) - Resolution 1920x1080, Position [0,0]

Screen 1 - Resolution 1920x1080, Position [0,1080]

I'm not sure how to test the second question

Comment: I could be wrong, but something tells me those two options (two windows or borderless fullscreen) is all you have.

Comment: I mean, if you for example open any Program and press F11 (on a regular ubuntu installation it should fullscreen the current application). Does it uses both or one screen in Fullscreen mode?

Comment: What's your GPU/monitor setup/topology?  Single GPU, multiple video outputs?  Multiple GPUs, single output per?  X11?  Wayland?  Framebuffer?  If X11, single `xorg.conf`-screen or [multiple](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#Separate_screens)?

Comment: `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` is defined as `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | 0x00001000`, so it's useless to pass `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP`. Both modes are exclusive anyway: you are in true fullscreen or you aren't. The fullscreen desktop mode is only called fullscreen because it makes the window borderless and take the size of the desktop.

Comment: I think HolyBlackCat is right. You can try listing the video displays and the display modes for each, but I doubt you will find a mode with resolution 1920x2160.